# Confusion regarding if and else part in navigation controller class in iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sdk

As we all know that the program flow either goes in if part or in else part(but never goes in both parts simultaneously). In the below code the flow is going inside both. I am unable to understand the reason behind.

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView          numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
    if (section == 0) {
        NSLog(@"section1 count is %d",boys.count);
        return boys.count;


    } 
    else {
        NSLog(@"section2 count1 is %d",girls.count);

        return girls.count;

    }

}
```

Comment: stick an NSLog outside the if/else. that should help you figure it out

Answer (score 2):

It goes inside both the blocks only if your table view contains more than 1 section and it goes either inside if block or else block per execution (it seems you have 2 sections).

Insert break points or log the section number before the if statements to make yourself clear.